# C compile IO error

Tags: c

I'm trying to output the contents of a buffer to a file but I'm getting compile error that I cannot decipher. Can someone clarify what I'm doing wrong and how to correct it. Thanks.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sdtio>

#define SERVER_PORT 4444    
#define BUF_SIZE 4096   
#define FILE *fptr

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

   fptr = fopen("TESTFILE.pdf", "wb");

   int c, s, bytes;
   char buf[BUF_SIZE];          
   struct hostent *h;           
   struct sockaddr_in channel;      

   if (argc != 3) fatal("Usage: client server-name file-name");
   h = gethostbyname(argv[1]);      
   if (!h) fatal("gethostbyname failed");

   s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
   if (s < 0) fatal("socket");
   memset(&channel, 0, sizeof(channel));
   channel.sin_family= AF_INET;
   memcpy(&channel.sin_addr.s_addr, h->h_addr, h->h_length);
   channel.sin_port= htons(SERVER_PORT);
   c = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *) &channel, sizeof(channel));
   if (c < 0) fatal("connect failed");

   write(s, argv[2], strlen(argv[2])+1);

   while (1) {
     bytes = read(s, buf, BUF_SIZE);    
     if (bytes <= 0) exit(0);   
     write(1, buf, bytes);      
 fputs(s,fptr);
   }
   fclose(fptr);
}

   fatal(char *string)
   {
      printf("%s\n", string);
      exit(1);
   }
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
p2Client2.c: In function âmainâ:
p2Client2.c:14: error: âfptrâ undeclared (first use in this function)
p2Client2.c:14: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
p2Client2.c:14: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

Comment: Aside from the font problem, how can such a clear message possibly be undecipherable? `fptr` is obviously undeclared. Even if it were correct to declare C variables with #define (a bizarre notion), your #define defines `FILE`, not `fptr`. Also, what is `<sdtio>`? Aside from misspelling stdio, C has stdio.h, not stdio.

Comment: Jim, Because I don't speak C. But appreciate your comment. Also while we're on the topic, the `fputs(s,fptr);` doesn't work either - not even sure if it's in a correct place. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to dive into the deep pool of answering questions from someone trying to write C programs who doesn't know C. I can barely fathom the extraordinarily bad judgment of undertaking such a task.

Answer (score 4):

Change `#define FILE *fptr` to `FILE *fptr`, like so:

```
FILE* fptr ;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

   fptr = fopen("TESTFILE.pdf", "wb");
  // do stuffs . . . 
}
```

`FILE` is not a user-defined macro, it is a type, like int, char. `fptr` is declared as a file pointer (FILE*).

Comment: I've made the correction and found out `fputs(s,fptr);` isn't working either.

Comment: The error seem irrelevant as the write method displays the content of the file.

Comment: No problem, can we address the `fputs(s,fptr);` issue still?